# Execution order of Maven build plugins during release:prepare

Tags: maven, plugins, release, execution

Today I observed a strange behavior in Maven 3 while preparing a release (with the Maven release plugin). As the description tends to be rather long, I would like to ask the question right before the description:

**How do I achieve to use the release plugin**

- so that the build fork executes plugins in the right order
- without having multiple executions of same plugins#
- and get a valid plugin.xml for the Mojo

The artifact to be released is a Maven plugin itself (Mojo with Annotations). When invoking the release:prepare goal it first starts the process in interactive mode asking for the new version data of the release. After that it forks a new process doing a "clean verify" on the project that's supposed to be released.

As described by the console output the execution order of the invocation is

1. clean
2. plugin:descriptor (Maven-plugin-plugin)
3. resources
4. compile
5. testResources
6. testCompile
7. test

It seems as if plugin:descriptor is not able to find any Mojos as compilation has not been taken place:

```
[INFO] [INFO] --- maven-plugin-plugin:3.2:descriptor (default-descriptor) @ concordion-maven-plugin ---
[INFO] [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to read mojo metadata, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] [INFO] Applying mojo extractor for language: java-annotations
[INFO] [INFO] Mojo extractor for language: java-annotations found 0 mojo descriptors.
```

When configured in the right way, the plugin fails because of no mojo found.

If I configure the release plugin to explicitly invoke the compile goal using

```
<preparationGoals>clean compile verify</preparationGoals>
```

the order of plugin execution changes to the following:

1. clean
2. plugin:descriptor (Maven-plugin-plugin)
3. resources
4. compile
5. plugin:descriptor (this time finding the Mojo annotation)
6. resources
7. compile
8. testResources
9. testCompile
10. test

As the Mojo is found the plugin.xml is created with all the necessary data.

This is the whole build section of my pom.

```
<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <fork>false</fork>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-plugin-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>
                            descriptor
                        </goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>true</skipErrorNoDescriptorsFound>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <dryRun>true</dryRun>
                <preparationGoals>clean compile verify</preparationGoals>
                <goals>deploy</goals>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Why have you changed the phase for maven-plugin-plugin. Use the default phase **process-classes**. Furthermore why you are using compile and verify as preparationGoals, cause compile in combination with verify does not make sense, cause verify contains compile. Why do you need preparationGoals? Does you plugin built correctly via mvn install? And it looks like you have missed **maven-plugin-annotations** dependency. May be you can show the full pom or the code location?